# How to delete a record that has a relationship

Tags: laravel

I want to delete a record that has a foreign key from another table, but at the time of performing the action it leaves me by some restriction. I would like to know if there is a way to delete it without deleting the other record that is related.

```
public function destroy($id) {
        try {
            $exists = Orderdetail::where('id', $id)->exists();
            if (!$exists) {
                return response()->json(
                    [
                        'message' => 'Error al eliminar la orden',
                        'status'  => 'error',
                        'data'    => 'La orden por este id no existe',

                    ], 500
                );
            }

            // eliminar la orden
            $order = Orderdetail::findOrFail($id);
            $order->delete();


        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return response()->json(
                [
                    'message' => 'Error al eliminar la orden',
                    'status'  => 'error',
                    'data'    => $th->getMessage(),

                ], 500
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: You will need to delete the related data too.

Comment: there is no way to do it without a home elimination ?

Comment: Try this method: `DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');` delete code and `DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to update the foreign key to have the [ON DELETE SET NULL](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete_null.php#:%7E:text=A%20foreign%20key%20with%20%22set%20null%20on%20delete%22%20means%20that,be%20deleted%20in%20SQL%20Server.) condition.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you may to change the engine of your database from InnoDB to MyISAM . But be careful, using MyISAM that means No data integrity (e.g. relationship constraints) check, which then comes a responsibility and overhead of the database administrators and application developers.